# Force text to start directly on the next line after a figure

Tags: floats

I'm currently writing the preface of my thesis. At the end of my thesis, I want to insert my signature (a picture). Directly below the picture I want to write my name, date and place.

However, I can't get the picture and text to be placed close to each other. When compiled, there is a gap between the picture and the text below.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Preface}

Preface text with some space after it.\\[3pc]

\FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{pics/signature}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\noindent  Stud. techn. Nemo \hfill  Sydney Harbour, May 30th 2003

\end{document}
```

Comment: why have you got a figure environment?

Comment: never end a paragraph with `\\ ` You must have underfull box warnings from `...t.\\[3pc]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Aureka! I thought I had to have the `\includegraphics` in a figure environment. Haha, well that solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `\\` at the end of a paragraph, `\includegraphics` in a `figure` and `\rule` in a `\makebox`, none of these constructs is helping, so:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Preface}

Preface text with some space after it.

\bigskip

\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}

\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

Stud. techn. Nemo \hfill  Sydney Harbour, May 30th 2003
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```